# Simple Django Admin App - How to track file versions

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

If I have a Django model with a FileField e.g.,

```
class Probe(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    nanoz_file = models.FileField(upload_to='nanoz_file', blank=True)
```

is there a way to prevent an uploaded file from being overwritten if a user uploads a new file in the Admin interface?

Also if I do keep the old files around is there a way I can relate the previous files back to the model instance?

I.e., I'd like to be able to list all files uploaded to the nanoz_file field for a given model instance.

Comment: Did you consider [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) ?

Comment: @jpic, that's interesting but it's probably overkill.  I just need a way to simply keep old files around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django never overwrites an uploaded file. If you upload 'foo.png' twice, the second will be 'foo_1.png' - I just tested this but don't take my word for it: try it too !

All you have to do (or let django-reversion do) is keep track of the previous file names.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this structure:

```
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files_storage/')
    belongs = models.ForeignKey('self')
    creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Then in the view you can use something like:

```
def edit_file(request, ...):
    # Get the file model instance
    file_model = ... # Code to get the instance
    # Create a new instance of the model with the old file path
    old_file = File(name='file1-v2', file=file_model.file, belongs=file_model)
    old_file.save()
    # Update the file_model with the new file data
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just as jpic said, you could try django-reversion, or

- track names of past files in sorts of DB, for example in seperated table row, in customized field or in gfk field.
- glob files online, as long as filename is managed.

For the second way, actually for dealing w/ all user uploads, its better to name the file by the pattern you designed instead of using the raw name (you could also store the raw name for later usage) . For your case, since the name field is unique, the field is suitable as the base for generating filename of the uploaded files, if it rarely changes:

```
import os.path
from django.hash_compat import sha_constructor

def upload_to(self, filename):  
    return 'nanoz_file/%s%s' % (
        sha_constructor(self.name).hexdigest(), os.path.splitext(filename)[-1])

class Probe(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    nanoz_file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to, blank=True)
```

Then in your view, you could fetch the list of names of all files of Probe instance probe by

```
import glob
# be careful to operate directory securely
glob.glob(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(probe.nanoz_file.path),
    '%s*' % sha_constructor(probe.name).hexdigest()))
```